# Why does an Element evaluate to false?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I am using elementtree and was wondering why an `Element` evaluates to `False`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

elt = ET.Element('foo')
if elt:
  print('bar')
```

I would expect "bar" to be printed because I have a valid `Element`, but it is not. Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Things with length zero are falsey. What does `len(elt)` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty element (just like an empty list or dict or other container) is falsey. Add a child to it, and it will be truthy

```
elt.append(ET.Element("bar"))
if elt:
    print("bar")
```

Outputs `bar`